# Replicate & Update SQL Server DB to AWS

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, migration, replication

We need to sync a client's on-premise SQL Server DB to AWS and keep it updated on a scheduled basis.
By client's request I feel forced to ask the following:
Is there any way to do this without RDS, DMS &/or EC2?

I believe this could be achieved in a somewhat unorthodox way through AWS Lambda, but since the original SQL Server DB contains a few +50gb tables I think the Lambda function would constantly run out of memory.

I've looked everywhere and haven't found an answer yet.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't run a database in Lambda. The database has to reside in RDS or EC2. So I really don't understand what you are proposing. DMS+RDS is Amazon's specific, purpose-built solution to this problem.

Comment: I know this sounds extremely dumb, but they do not want to replicate the Database, they want to replicate the tables as files (csv preferably).
I know the serverless nature of Lambda limits its usage and it cannot be used to run a database, what I meant was to create a Lambda job to perform a request to the on-premise database, and then update AWS' replica of said DB.

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly possible with Lambda but it presents some challenges. You would have to split the jobs into tasks that would fit within the [limits of the Lambda runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html), which at this time include 15 minutes max execution time, 3,008 MB RAM, and 512 MB disk space. If the CSVs are too large to fit within those limits, and you want the entire CSV to be processed in a single database transaction, then it may not be possible to implement using Lambda.

I would suggest having a process that pushes the CSVs to S3 which can then trigger Lambda functions directly, or add the file ingest tasks to an SQS queue or Kinesis stream to then be processed by Lambda functions.

Comment: This does, in fact, seem complicated with Lambda.
Would you recommend going through the common [RDS+DMS] route?

Comment: Yes, I recommended using RDS+DMS with my first comment to your question and I still recommend that. Why re-invent the DMS service yourself when Amazon has already spent so much time and effort creating it for you?